# Sum value of textboxes in an excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

How do I get the sum of multiple textboxes and put the value in a cell.
Is there a way to do it in a function?
Like a1 f(x) = "=Textbox1 + Textbox2"

Comment: first parse the values to numbers (e.g. `int`), afterwards perform your calculation. Last transform back to string using `ToString`. To give you more help you should first be more specific on what you've tried yourself and where exactly you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a loop,
Then chain the index to the textbox name.

for example:

```
      int sum=0;
      for(i=1; i< [number of the textbox you have]; i++){
          sum+=Parse.toInt32(Textbox+i);               
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the above will work as is.  You need to get the textbox object first and then get its value.  Something like

```
Textbox tb;
int sum = 0;
for (i=1; 1<[numberof the textbox you have];i++)
{ tb = (TextBox)(this.Controls("tbItem" + intItemCount.toString()).Text);
 sum += int.Parse(tb.Text);
}
```